# How to deal with double composition and inheritance?

Tags: objective-c, oop, inheritance, composition

I found this related question: [How do I use composition with inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279158/how-do-i-use-composition-with-inheritance)

I would like to do the same with Objective-C, that is to say that a `GenericView` knows that its property `obj` is a GenericObject, and that a `SpecializedView` knows that the very same `obj` property is a `SpecializedObject`.

Here is an example that will be clearer:

```
//
//  Example.m

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

/* HEADER */

// Electrical Machine
@interface ElectricalMachine : NSObject {
}
- (void)plugIn;

@end

// Toaster
@interface Toaster : ElectricalMachine {
}
- (float)getThermostat;

@end

// GenericView
@interface GenericView : NSObject {
    ElectricalMachine *machine;
}
- (void)doSomethingGeneric;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ElectricalMachine *machine;

@end

//SpecializedView
@interface SpecializedView : GenericView {
}
- (void)doSomethingSpecialized;
@end


/* IMPLEMENTATION */

// GenericView
@implementation GenericView

@synthesize machine;

- (void)doSomethingGeneric {
    Toaster *toaster = [[Toaster alloc] init];
    [toaster plugIn];
    self.machine = toaster;
    [toaster release];
}

@end

// SpecializedView
@implementation SpecializedView

- (void)doSomethingSpecialized {
    /* ERROR HERE
     * Incompatible types in initialization
     * 'ElectricalMachine' may not respond to '-getThermostat'
     */
    float r = [machine getThermostat];
    r = r;
    // ...
}

@end
```

As you see, I get an error at the end, because for `SpecializedView` the machine property is an `ElectricalMachine`, not a `Toaster`.

Thank you very much for your help!

**Old Question**

Here is the first version of my question, which was maybe too cryptic:

I have the following generic view:

```
@interface GenericView {
    GenericObject obj;
}

- (id)doSomething;
```

I also have the following specialized view:

```
@interface SpecializedView : GenericView {
}

- (id)doSomethingElse;
```

I have the following object:

```
@interface GenericObject {
}

- (id)plugIn;
```

and the following specialized object:

```
@interface SpecializedObject : GenericObject {
}

- (float)toastTime;
```

Let's say I want GenericView to handle GenericObject, and SpecializedView to handle the same object, knowing that it is SpecializedObject.

Let me explain by showing implementations:

**GenericView doSomething**

```
- (id)doSomething {
    [obj plugIn];
}
```

**SpecializedView doSomethingElse**

```
- (id)doSomethingElse {
    // ERROR here
    float time = [obj toastTime];
}
```

I will get the following warning:
    'GenericObject' may not respond to '-toastBread'
and the following error:
    Incompatible types in assignement

Which is logical, since I have defined the type of obj as GenericObject. I want to be able to use methods from GenericObject in GenericView, and methods from SpecializedObject in SpecializedView. Is there a way to precise that obj has to be a GenericObject in GenericView to be handled, and has to be a SpecializedObject to be dealt with in SpecializedView, without adding a property? How would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C is a dynamically-typed language and methods are resolved at runtime, not compile time. If in `SpecializedView`, `obj` is in fact of an object of type `SpecializedObject` (even though it's declared as `GenericObject`), it will in fact respond to a `toastBread` message. The compiler will generate a warning but you can ignore it.

If `SpecializedView` may have both `GenericObjects` and `SpecializedObjects`, you can make *sure* that `obj` responds to `toastBread` using the `respondsToSelector:` message (inherited from `NSObject`):

```
if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(toastBread)]) {
    [obj toastBread];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your solution but for a reason I don't understand, it does not work. Let's say that I am trying to get a value from [obj toastTime], and it won't work. Compilation says: "incompatible types in assignment". I tried to add an abstract method in GenericObject, but it won't work.

Comment: In your example, `toastTime` returns an object of type `id`, but you're assigning it to a `float`. An `id` is not a `float` (it's actually a pointer) and thus cannot be assigned to a variable of type `float`.

Comment: Sorry, my example was wrong, even by defining the type that toastTime returns as a ‘float‘, it won't work.

Comment: To remove the warning you have to cast the object to the type you know it to be. [(Toaster *)obj toastTime];

Comment: Thank you very much monowerker, your solution is perfect!